# angular js internet explorer refreshing issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, internet-explorer-11

I have been testing our angular app in IE 11 and while it's surprisingly fast considering it's IE there is an issue with refreshing our single page app. that said, we are still in the development phase and did not minify our resources hence initial load before caching in eg chrome takes 7 secs while in IE it takes about 17 or smth. to fix $http calls caching in IE 11 we have added the following two lines

config file

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
```

any idea from which side to approach this ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like cache issue. Internet explorer not updating old data. [internal explorer caching isue](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/AngularJS-caching-issue-for-Internet-Explorer) this might help you.

Comment: if you see the two lines of code I added, those are needed unless http calls dont update content in IE...basically caching is removed...dont know if it possible to actually fix both